# Is Bounty Equivalent to Advertising Fee? Wished it had a Warning Message Box!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since you will never get back the bounty offered. Its more like a advertising medium. The term bounty confuses many user as in real life an unclaimed bounty return to the original owner. Yes it is clearly stated inside the bounty rules and regulation, but how many of us read the listed rules. One only learns from mistake.

Why shouldn't we rename bounty or put a high alert message when a bounty is clicked. A simple message stating no refund for further information click here could save a dumb person like me whom failed to read the bounty rules and regulation at the first place.

Comment: You're right that it's more like advertising, there is a warning "(this reputation is deducted immediately and cannot be refunded)" but for some reason in it's small text when it could be made larger without making the pop-up wider. Not sure about changing the name, that might confuse existing users and they'd be a huge number of faq / help / meta pages that'd need updating. It'd also likely be a network-wide change, I'm pretty confident a moderator here couldn't change it and SE would be unlikely to change a core function on a single site.

Comment: @PeterJ omg, I just saw the warning. Why is it so small. Didn't even notice it last time. Furthermore it is in light gray color. Red ink and bold should be used instead.

Comment: Don't blame your screwup on the system.  There are only three lines of text, so no need to highlight any of them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I admit I did screw up. Idiots like me do exist.  That's the reason [Poka Yoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke) was invented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky because the system can't guarantee an answer for every bounty. Part of the mechanism of "no refunds" is there to prevent questions from staying up on the "featured" tab indefinitely for no cost (or if you don't like the answers you got).

[image]

Comment: Yup, seems blatantly clear.

Comment: Also, somebody who wants others to put extra work into an answer shouldn't be able to dangle a reward, get what they wanted, and then pull the reward back at no cost to themselves.

Answer (score 4):

From the Dictionary:

```
boun·ty noun \ˈbau̇n-tē\

1:  something that is given generously
2:  liberality in giving :  generosity
3:  yield especially of a crop
4:  a reward, premium, or subsidy especially when offered or given by a government: as
a :  an extra allowance to induce entry into the armed services
b :  a grant to encourage an industry
c :  a payment to encourage the destruction of noxious animals
d :  a payment for the capture of or assistance in the capture of an outlaw
```

Our use isn't quite in the scope of the formal definition, but it shouldn't be a surprise it's a payout.